# configuring httpd conf in aws

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services

I would like to update `httpd conf in elastic beanstalk` so I could set the `AllowOverride all` and hence allow myself to execute the following `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?category/([^/d]+)/?$ searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the htaccess file is located in the root

To configure httpd conf I am trying to follow the below guide:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

My problems are as follow:

- My computer does not allow me to create a folder called
  `.ebextensions` - it won't accept the dot in front of exbextensions

I will place the `.config` file inside the exbentension with the following code:

```
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/your/htdocs/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I am not sure if I am following/executing things properly, and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: have you tried typing `mkdir .ebextensions` in command line?

Comment: could you elaborate more on that?

Comment: oh that worked. thanks. why would it only work in command line though?

Comment: open a console (`cmd` in windows) and type the command `mkdir .ebextensions` in it. This will create the `.ebextensions` folder in the current directory (something like `c:\users\user3907211\.ebextensions`), which you will be able to copy where it belongs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Explorer doesn't allow you to create file names starting with `.` I believe the reason for this lies in [DOS file names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) which had separate fields for name and extension, and file name could not be empty.

The only workaround I know is to use `mkdir` to create directories starting with `.`:

```
mkdir .ebextensions
```

Similarly, if you have troubles to create a file starting with a `.`, you can use:

```
echo > .config
```

This will create an empty file named `.config` which you will be able to modify with notepad for example.

Comment: thanks for solving the first part of my dilemma. my second is the following: is am not sure if what is written in the .config as written in my initial post does actually allow htaccess to work as when I uploaded the instance it did not rewrite/cleanup the url as intented

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you with this part. Hope you'll get more answers addressing this issue.

Comment: Late but FWIW you *can* create file names starting with `.` in Windows but you have to append a `.` as well. For example, to create the `.ebextensions` the directory in a Windows environment one would need to name the new directory `.ebextensions.` Note the trailing `.` It doesn't display but forces Windows to cooperate.